# showModalBottomsheet adds listview as a child Widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-showmodalbottomsheet

showModalBottomsheet adds listview as a child Widget. When listview slides to the top, how to respond to the bottom sheet drop-down gesture by continuing to pull down

```
showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        isScrollControlled: true,
        constraints: BoxConstraints(
          maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.85),
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topRight: Radius.circular(20),
              topLeft: Radius.circular(20)),
        ),
        builder: (context) {
          return ListView.builder(
                      controller: scrollController,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
                            title: Text(index.toString()),
                            onTap: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                          ));
        });
```

Comment: Sorry. Can you make the question more clear?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DraggableScrollableSheet`

```dart
showModalBottomSheet(
  context: context,
  isScrollControlled: true,
  constraints: BoxConstraints(
      maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.85),
  shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
        topRight: Radius.circular(20), topLeft: Radius.circular(20)),
  ),
  builder: (context) {
    return DraggableScrollableSheet(
      builder: (context, scrollController) {
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 32,
          controller: scrollController,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
            title: Text(index.toString()),
            onTap: () => Navigator.pop(context),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  },
);
```

Find more about [DraggableScrollableSheet decoration](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/DraggableScrollableSheet-class.html)